# libGDX texture packer runnable-texturepacker.jar won't open

Tags: java, android, jar, libgdx

I want to run  `runnable-texturepacker.jar` (libgdx texture packer) but when i double click on this file nothing happens. I'm unable to run texture packer.
Previously I use `gdx-texturepacker.jar` and this file opens fine, but this is old version and I have problems with nine patch images.

I've installed new version of java JRE but file won't run , also I try with `java -jar <file name>` command but `runnable-texturepacker.jar` won't run.

I'm able to open jar files except this one. I downloaded this file from  [this link](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/runnables/)

Here is explanation about Texture Packer but I'm not very familiar with this [texture packer](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Texture-packer)

Please give me any tips for this

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

its a command line java application, without gui.

```
java -jar runnable-texturepacker.jar 
Usage: inputDir [outputDir] [packFileName] [settingsFileName]
```